# iOS - How to calc width of a default textLabel of UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, width

I tried the code below, but the output is always 0.000000:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellNotification";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Test Test Test. I am a cell.";

    NSLog(@"%f", cell.textLabel.frame.size.width);

    return cell;
}
```

How can I know what the width of a default UITableViewCell is? I need this information because I have to set the height for UITableViewCell in

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: For the call
`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
you dont need the width you only need to return the height.

Comment: Not much of an answer, but I'd go for "300". It will probably break on the next iOS update, but so will the rest of your app :)

Comment: Can you tell me how you get the number? Thanks!

Comment: Trial and error. The width of the whole iPhone screen is 320, and for a grouped `UITableView` it's about 10px less on each side. I also looked for a way to compute that width, but have to admit I eventually gave up.

Comment: The width is exactly 300. I appended a label as subview to match the default textLabel. I am still looking for some methods to get it by programmatically, so please help.

Comment: The width will vary depending on a number of factors, such as iOS version, device type, orientation, if the table is plain or grouped etc. All auto size solutions Ive found so far use hard coded width approximations, which is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The `NSLog` you are using above is asking for the width of the textLabel within the cell, not the actual cell.

```
NSLog(@"%f",cell.frame.size.width);
```

Additionally, if you aren't using the grouped table style, the cells width should return the same as the width of the table.

**EDIT:** I'm not really sure if this was the question, but if you're asking how to set the width of your cells, you don't have to. This is handled for you.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(cell.textLabel.frame));
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Try changing this:

```
if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Test Test Test. I am a cell.";
```

To this:

```
if (cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = @"Test Test Test. I am a cell.";
```

Comment: The width of the label is different from the width of the cell because there are padding. And why is the width of textLabel zero?

Comment: I am not going to set the width of cells. I just need the width so I can do something like: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [@"A string" sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt" size:16] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(THE WIDTH OF THE LABEL, 20000.0f) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation].height + 35;
}

Comment: The width of the label is different from the width of the cell because of padding. I have to know the width of label, not cell.

Comment: No, the same result. I can omit the brackets if there is only one line, right?

Comment: @iForests I believe so, I'm just running out of ideas as to why this isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

The width of the cell will be the width of the table, unless your table is grouped, in which case it is slightly smaller.

However, you probably want the width of whatever label you are using to display the text rather than the cell itself.

A further warning is that the `heightForRow...` method is called for every row in the table before any cells are created, so you may have to use a known value instead.

Comment: The width of the label is different from the width of the cell because of padding. I have to know the width of label, not cell.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should test your textLabel width in:
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: I believe that this is the first time you will be able to access the UI elements. By this, the text label will be sized to fit its cell. However, this occurs after heightForRow... has been called.